# how to create google charts in a loop

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, charts, google-visualization

Hi i am working on google charts everything is working fine. Charts are loading perfectly but now iam in a situation where i need to load charts in a loop and i am unable to latebind charts. heres the C# mvc code

```
<table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <% Html.RenderPartial("ChartsDetailPDF", ViewData); %> //this chart code is working fine

                </td>
            </tr>
            <% var allChildCategories = ViewData["allChildCategories"] as List<Category>;

               if (allChildCategories != null)
               {
                   foreach (var item in allChildCategories)
                   {
                       var categoryId = item.Id; 
                       // from here i need categoryId and from this id i can get jsondata from server calling ajax function
            %>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <script>
     $(document).ready(function () {

 google.load('visualization', '1.1', { 'packages': ['corechart'], 'callback': drawChartLateBinding("<%=categoryId %>", "<%=userId %>", "<% =startDate %>", "<% =endDate %>") }); 

      });
 function drawChartLateBinding(categoryId ,userId,startDate,endDate) {
                $('#chartControlRepeater' + categoryId).load( function () { 
                    drawBarChartAjaxfunction(categoryId, userId, startDate, endDate);
                }); 


                    </script>

                   <div  id="chartDiv_<%=categoryId %>" data-categoryId="<%=categoryId%>" data-userId="<%=userId %>" data-startdate="<% =startDate %>" data-enddate="<% =endDate %>" style="width: 100%; height: 450px;">
                  </div>                                     
                </td>
            </tr>

            <%}
               } %>
 </table>
```

Comment: I think you are missing a tag, Im not sure if that is Razor, but what ever it is it wont work if you just write it with javascript. you need to render it with the engine you are using first, or write it as plain Html

Comment: the tag should be missing in stackoverflow code somehow

Comment: i am not using razor its simple c# old asp style  inline code

Comment: my concern is  foreach loop how should i initialize charts my code is not working

Answer (score 0):

The question is not clear (or i didn't understand) but this are the basic steps for chart initalisation and draw:

```
var chart_data_categoryId = new google.visualization.DataTable(data);
var chart_categoryId = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById(chart_div_categoryId));
chart_categoryId.draw(chart_data_categoryId, options);
```